# Adding Values with int.parse

Tags: c#, excel

I'm looping through some excel cells to sum the values of the cells, some of the cells are empty and i'm getting a `Input string was not in the correct format` error when I pass them. Here's my code:

```
     int total = 0;
        int rowstart = 4;
        while (ws.Cells[rowstart, 1].Value.ToString() != "")
        {
           if (ws.Cells[rowstart, 1].Value.ToString() !=
                      ws.Cells[rowstart + 1, 1].Value.ToString())
           {
               ws.InsertRow(rowstart + 1, 1);
               ws.Cells[rowstart + 1, 3].Value = total;
           }
           else
           {
         total = total + int.Parse(ws.Cells[rowstart, 3].Value.ToString()); 
// I'm adding the value of Column 3 to the variable total, 
I get the error if the cell is empty
               rowstart = rowstart + 1;
           }
        }
```

I was thinking it's because you can't parse an empty string, so how do I just add 0 if the cell is empty?

Comment: Can you provide what type `ws.Cells[rowstart, 3].Value` is?

Comment: @Kamo What do you mean by type? the values in the cells are either whole numbers or empty cells. I'm having problems with adding if the loop passes by an empty cell.

Comment: Do you wanna add `0` **only** if your cell is empty or when this cell does not contain a valid integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `int.TryParse`:

```
int parsed;
int.TryParse(ws.Cells[rowstart, 3].Value.ToString(), out parsed)
total += parsed;
```

`parsed` will be 0 if the string wasn't a number.

Comment: It seems like `int.TryParse` really guarantees that the `out` parameter is set to `0` if the parsing fails. Still, I'd probably go with: `if (int.TryParse(...)) { total += parse; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`

```
int total = 0;
int rowstart = 4;

while (ws.Cells[rowstart, 1].Value.ToString() != "")
{
int val=0;
if (ws.Cells[rowstart, 1].Value.ToString() != ws.Cells[rowstart + 1, 1].Value.ToString())
{
   ws.InsertRow(rowstart + 1, 1);
   ws.Cells[rowstart + 1, 3].Value = total;
}
else
{ 
int.TryParse(ws.Cells[rowstart, 3].Value.ToString(), out val);
    total = total + val; 
   // I'm adding the value of Column 3 to the variable total, I get the error if the cell is empty
   rowstart = rowstart + 1;
}

}
```

Comment: `TryParse` returns a `bool` indicating if the given `string` was parsable or not. So `val=int.TryParse(...)` shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @Corak sorry it was typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
else
{ 
  If (int.TryParse(ws.Cells[rowstart, 3].Value.ToString(), out result))
    total = total +int.Parse(ws.Cells[rowstart, 3].Value.ToString());

   rowstart = rowstart + 1;
}
```